# What is wrong in my bubble sort using ArrayList?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

What is wrong in my bubble sort in ArrayList? It was not sorted . I am a beginner.

```
public static ArrayList < Integer > bubbleSort(ArrayList < Integer > ar) {

    for (int i = 0; i < ar.size() - 1; i++) {
        int indexMax = i;
        for (int j = 1; j < ar.size(); j++) {
            if (ar.get(indexMax) > ar.get(j)) {
                indexMax = j;
            }
        }
        if (indexMax != i) {
            int temp = ar.get(i);
            ar.set(i, ar.get(indexMax));
            ar.set(indexMax, temp);
        }
    }
    return ar;

}
```

Comment: As your are using ArrayList then you can also use collection methods to sort your integer ascending as well as descending order

Comment: Welcome to SO! First of all, you should learn how to format your code, it will make it more readable, therefore we will be able to help you faster. 
Bubble sort is a classic algorithm, so you can find a lot of examples and compare your solution with them. Anyway, I posted an answer which I tested. I also noted some of your mistakes

Comment: @Kandy I think he is practicing and his task states to implement **bubble** sort.

Comment: @Steyrix May be he is learning I am only sending approaches that he can try to achieve there goal. this will make him to know about Collection framework if he is beginner which can helpful to him as well as other beginner who visit this post.

Comment: @Steyrix what is format in your code ? get me more info Please.

Comment: @hadiRezaee your square brackets were positioned in wrong way and the indents were not right. However, some people edited your post and now the code looks fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your swapping code block looked like it was outside of loop, so the only one swap occurred for one iteration of main loop. 
You are also doing unnecessary comparing of elements, starting your inner loop with precondition `j = 1`. You should start it from `i`, as after some iterations of outer loop range from 0 to `i` will be already sorted.

I think you can use a simpler approach.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ar.size() - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < ar.size(); j++) {
        if (ar.get(j) < ar.get(i)) {
            Integer temp = ar.get(j);
            ar.set(j, ar.get(i));
            ar.set(i, temp);       
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, swapping takes place inside of the inner loop, and it also skips already sorted part of collection.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you should start from 2nd element `(j=1)` every time?
Try `j=i`. i.e.,

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> bubbleSort (ArrayList<Integer> ar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.size() - 1; i++) {
        int indexMax = i;            
        for (int j = i; j < ar.size(); j++) {
            if (ar.get(indexMax) > ar.get(j)) {
                indexMax = j;
            }
        }
        if (indexMax != i) {
            int temp = ar.get(i);
            ar.set(i, ar.get(indexMax));
            ar.set(indexMax, temp);
        }
    }
    return ar;
}
```

P.S this will sort your array in *ascending* order.

Comment: Please do not encourage poor code indenting. Format your code properly before posting an answer

Comment: It won't sort in descending order, since the order of progression is in the opposite way as the traditional bubble sort, but it also looks for the minimum value (in contrast to what the variable name says). This implementation does work, however, it is written very confusingely. It's mechanism is in the spirit of bubble sort.

Comment: @hadiRezaee I would look at the wiki page of bubble sort, there are some animations that should show you, how bubble sort is meant to work. :) Maybe that helps you to derive a cleaner implementation of it.

Comment: @brimborium i looked at the wiki page and it was very helpful thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do sorting like this:

```
for(int out=inputArray.size()-1; out>0; out--){
    for(int j=1; j<=out; j++){
      if(inputArray[j-1]<inputArray[j]){
         //Swap the elements
         int temp = inputArray[j];
         inputArray[j]=inputArray[j-1];
         inputArray[j-1]=temp;
       }
     }
 }
return inputArray;
```

Comment: He is using `ArrayList`, not an array. So your answer may be not very clear to OP, since he is beginner

Answer (score 0):

Can you try that?

```
int n = arr.length; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) 
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
            { 
                // swap arr[j+1] and arr[i] 
                int temp = arr[j]; 
                arr[j] = arr[j+1]; 
                arr[j+1] = temp; 
            }
```